# Anyway to use two .onclick event handlers from two different scripts on one button?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use two .onclick event handlers on the same button when the event handlers are stored in two different scripts? I know it would be easy to just call the two functions I need into the same .onclick handler, but I'm curious if there's a way around this.

Suppose I have

script1.js

```
someButton.onclick = function() {
    someFunction1();

}
```

script2.js

```
someButton.onclick = function() {
    someFunction2();

}
```

Running these scripts in the html in this order would lead to calling someFunction2() onclick, as I assume the functionality of the button is overwritten by script2.js.

Comment: Why do you assume that? Also, why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: I have tried it. If you include script1.js and then script2.js in the html file, the .onclick calls someFunction2(). I've read that the order that you include the <script>s shouldn't matter, but when I tested it, it did matter. I assume that when script2.js runs, it reassigns the value of the onclick attribute for someButton instead of adding to someButton's functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) and this will add both the event handlers to the element on contrast to replacing the `onclick` attribute of the element.

```
someButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
   someFunction1();

});
someButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
   someFunction2();

});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dTLKp/)**

Answer (score 0):

*addEventListener* is the way to go here, but if you were to stick with `someButton.onclick`, I would do this:

```
var old = someButton.onclick;

someButton.onclick = function (event) {
    if (typeof old === 'function') {
        old.call(someButton, event); // call the old listener
    }

    someFunction2(); // run new code
};
```

It saves a reference to the old onclick function, and makes a new onclick function that will not only call the old onclick function, but run whatever other code you want as well.